# ¿Como creo un tablero en android para un buscaminas?

Tags: java, android-studio

**Este es el codigo que tengo por ahora ,necesitaba hacer un tablero en un grid o layout**
Probe muchas cosas pero nada me funciona :(

```
    private void crearTablero(String fraseimportada){
        String fraseImportada=fraseimportada;
        if (fraseImportada=="Facil") {
            filas = 8;
            columnas = 8;
            minas = 10;
            totalceldas = 64;
        }
        if (fraseImportada=="Medio") {
            filas = 16;
            columnas = 16;
            minas = 40;
            totalceldas = 256;
        }
        if (fraseImportada=="Dificil") {
            filas = 30;
            columnas = 16;
            minas = 99;
            totalceldas = 480;
        }
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].